# WooCommerce If Statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am working on an if statement that determines whether the user is logged in and whether they have purchased the product already.

I have found the following code determines this correctly:

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $product;
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() )):
?>
```

However I wish to adjust this so that I can display separate content when the user is logged in.

I have spent some hours trying to incorporate the above code into a traditional loop but have been unsuccessful.

The following works:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ): ?>

    <h1>Logged In</h1>

<?php else: ?>

    <h1>Logged Out</h1>

<?php endif ?>
```

But when I add the markup to determine if the product has been purchased, I receive errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you want to show content but i assume on the single product page following code will work

```
function showMyNotice(){
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $product;
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if ( wc_customer_bought_product( $current_user->user_email, $current_user->ID, $product->get_id() )){

          echo "You have this product already";

        }else{
          echo "You need to buy the product"; 
        }

}else{
  echo "You need to buy the product"; 
}

}



add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'showMyNotice', 20 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try restrict content, content control etc plugins which does the job. Try searching for plugins with shortcodes where you can wrap restricted content within shortcodes to check if user is logged in.